# Jquery Hide divs & Show div

Tags: jquery, hide, show

I want a couple of  to hide with one id and one  to show.

Right now I have this:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#showhidetarget').hide();

        $('a#showhidetrigger').click(function () {
            $('#about_me').toggle(1200);
        });
    });
```

So the #about_me section hides on a#showhidetrigger but it also shows if I click again. What do I need to add if I want another id to trigger the show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
$(document).ready(function () {         

        $('a#showhidetrigger').click(function () {
            $('#about_me').hide(1200);
        });

        $('#idOfSomeother').click(function () {
            $('#about_me').show(1200);
        });

});
```

Comment: Thank you Mr Adil. THat worked perfect and made sense. 

What if I have a section I want only to be visible when you enter the site and if you  press the logo(home)?

Answer (score 0):

try this

add another trigger element..with and id ..lets say...`id= "hideshowtrigger"`.. this shows the aboutme....

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('a#showhidetrigger').click(function () {
        $('#about_me').show();
   });

   $('#hideshowtrigger').click(function () {

        $('#about_me').hide();
    });
});
```